# GMail: Get Thread Count from Labels on a Delegated Account (Alias)

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to get a count of emails that have a specific label. The following works on my account but I'm not sure exactly how to get it to work on an alias account which is my group inbox.

```
function countEmailwLabelsEnterprise(){
  var tss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var dailyUpdateCalcSht = tss.getSheetByName('Daily Update Calculator');

  var labelName = dailyUpdateCalcSht.getRange('B32').getValue();
  var label = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName(labelName);
  var mails = label.getThreads();
  dailyUpdateCalcSht.getRange('B13').setValue(mails.length);
}
```

I have a very basic understanding of alias accounts with google scripts so I would appreciate an answer that explains how and why it works.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you run the script, the user identity associated with the script are as follows:

[image]

Granting delegate access to another account sends an invitation email to confirm access, which it does not give the same authorization whenever you are asking permission to run the script. Delegate rights are only accessible through the Gmail Interface.

**Reference:**

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/authorization
https://support.google.com/mail/answer/138350